# Automatic authentication to SMTP server takes very long in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtplib

I’m sending email via smtplib and SMTP server does not require authentication/login.
When I send without login it takes around 10 seconds to send an email and with an explicit login only a fraction of a second.

I also tested with some command line tools like “SwithcMail” and “mailsend-go" and these apps send an email within a fraction of a second **without** authentication.

So in my thinking it must be something in smtplib that is causing this delay. Any clues, suggestions, fixes?

Thanks in advance.

Added code:

```
SMTP_SERVER = mail_smtp
USERNAME_SMTP = mail_smtpuser
PASSWORD_SMTP = 'MyPassword'

SENDER = mail_from
RECIPIENTS = mail_to
RECIPIENTS_CC = mail_cc
RECIPIENTS_ALL = mail_to + mail_cc + mail_bcc

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = mail_subject
msg['From'] = SENDER
msg['To'] = RECIPIENTS
msg['Cc'] = RECIPIENTS_CC
msg.set_content(mail_body)

with smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER) as smtp:
  smtp.ehlo()
  smtp.starttls()
  smtp.ehlo()
  if SENDER == USERNAME_SMTP:
     smtp.login(USERNAME_SMTP, PASSWORD_SMTP)
  smtp.sendmail(SENDER, RECIPIENTS_ALL, msg.as_string())
  smtp.close()
```

Added debug level: I always get two "Invalid address" replies on rcpt TO, but without authentication the server takes 5 seconds to respond (2x5=10 seconds delay). Not sure what this means now and what should/can be fixed.

```
With authentication:
15:29:27.071517 send: 'rcpt TO:<MyEmail@comp.com\r\n'
15:29:27.104498 reply: b'250 2.1.5 Recipient OK\r\n'
15:29:27.104498 reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'2.1.5 Recipient OK'
15:29:27.104498 send: 'rcpt TO:<>\r\n'
15:29:27.138559 reply: b'501 5.1.3 Invalid address\r\n'
15:29:27.138559 reply: retcode (501); Msg: b'5.1.3 Invalid address'
15:29:27.138559 send: 'rcpt TO:<>\r\n'
15:29:27.171532 reply: b'501 5.1.3 Invalid address\r\n'
15:29:27.171532 reply: retcode (501); Msg: b'5.1.3 Invalid address'

Without authentication:
15:30:04.185904 send: 'rcpt TO:<MyEmail@comp.com>\r\n'
15:30:04.220843 reply: b'250 2.1.5 Recipient OK\r\n'
15:30:04.220843 reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'2.1.5 Recipient OK'
15:30:04.220843 send: 'rcpt TO:<>\r\n'
15:30:09.255583 reply: b'501 5.1.3 Invalid address\r\n'
15:30:09.255583 reply: retcode (501); Msg: b'5.1.3 Invalid address'
15:30:09.255583 send: 'rcpt TO:<>\r\n'
15:30:14.294954 reply: b'501 5.1.3 Invalid address\r\n'
15:30:14.294954 reply: retcode (501); Msg: b'5.1.3 Invalid address'
```

Comment: And, of course, run with a profiler to see where your code is spending time.

Comment: I added some code and debug details

Answer (score 0):

Issue is fixed now.
I exclude empty Cc and Bcc from RECIPIENTS_ALL and everything works OK.

```
# split and remove empty strings ('' and ' ')
mail_cc = list(filter(str.strip, mail_cc.split(',')))
mail_bcc = list(filter(str.strip, mail_bcc.split(',')))

RECIPIENTS_ALL = mail_to
if mail_cc:
    RECIPIENTS_ALL += mail_cc
if mail_bcc:
    RECIPIENTS_ALL += mail_bcc
```